# Trying to make the bot display the member count in its activity

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am wanting this to change the member count on the bot's status bu cant seem to figure it out.

```py
members = 31

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
        members + 1 

# updates members
@client.event
async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Server Name " + str(members) + " Members!"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please, ask properly your question, with what, how, etc ... Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a bot that will be in multiple servers:

```py
# Excludes bots
member_count = sum([len([m for m in g.members if not m.bot]) for g in client.guilds])

# Includes bots
member_count = sum([g.member_count for g in client.guilds])
```

However, if you're just going to be using a bot in one server, then this will suffice:

```py
# Excludes bots
member_count = len([m for m in Guild.members if not m.bot])

# Includes bots
Guild.member_count

# Side-note:
# Guild is simply the guild object that your bot is in.
# Depending on what you've called paramters -
# If you're using command decorators, you'd want ctx.guild,
# or if you're in an on_message() event, you'll want message.guild,
# or if you're somewhere else, you can use get_guild(112233445566778899)
```

With that being said, the first examples *will* work with the bot just being in one server, but they're just a tad bit overkill.

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members)
- [`Guild.member_count`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.member_count)
- [`Guild.chunked`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.chunked) - If you have issues getting the member count for whatever reason, you might want to look into this and [`client.request_offline_members()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.request_offline_members).
- [`Client.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild)